How come my add_to_cart event does not show item data?
In GA4, when I go to Reports > Engagement > Events > add_to_cart, there are no item parameters displaying in the "Parameter Name" drop down or the two blocks below that, they just show "No data available".

When I follow the add_to_cart action in DebugView, the item parameters all come through. So it looks like GA should be collecting this data and putting it in this report.

Am I missing a step to get this data to show up as expected? How is this report supposed to work? We have this same/similar issue for all of our events.
